Request Level Tracing and OpenTelemetry
We have Springboot applications for which we enabled "request level" tracing based on a HTTP request header (Uses DynamicThresholdFilter).
Now we are implementing Open Telemetry and considering that it would be nice to propagate the
"run with debug logging enabled" flag to all the services that are used by the original request.
Does OpenTelemetry include flags to tell the receiving application to run in debug?
I wonder if we should include custom flags in the tracestate header, or create our own header
and configure the framework to propagate it.
Thanks!
